# Custom template for fields in user profiles

Tags: theming, users, entities

I'd like to customize the fields in my user profiles. So far I've created `field.tpl.php` which of course applies to all fields on my whole website and not only to the fields in the user profiles.

How do I have to name the `field.tpl.php`? Is it `field--user-profiles.tpl.php`? That didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Drupal's [theme hook suggestions for Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) the following suggested template names are available:

1. field--field-name--content-type.tpl.php
2. field--content-type.tpl.php
3. field--field-name.tpl.php
4. field--field-type.tpl.php

The `content-type` in this case is `user` (I guess it means entity type really), so to theme fields just for user profile pages, your template should be called:

```
field--user.tpl.php
```

I've just tested that on a dev site and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a template for whole form by altering form

I assume that you didnt use profile2 module. Your user profile(maybe account) page is at user/1/edit

first of all you need write alter function

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id){
    case 'user_profile_form':
      //load an entity object
      $form['#theme'] = 'custom_profile_form';
    break;
}}
```

then you have to add own template for this form item

like

```
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    // user profile 2 form
    'custom_profile_form'=>array(
      'render element'=>'form',
      'template'=>'custom-profile-form'
    ),
```

then you have to create custom-profile-form.tpl.php in your modules folder

in this template file you have to render some form specific variables

```
<form action="<?php print $form['#action']; ?>" method="<?php print $form['#method']; ?>"
        id="<?php print $form['#id']; ?>" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <?php print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']); ?>
    <?php print drupal_render($form['form_token']); ?>
    <?php print drupal_render($form['form_id']); ?>
//here you have to render own elements

</form>
```

rendering fields like this will give field form elements without waste divs that core attaches

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['profile_profile']['field_status']['und'][0])?>
```

templates like field.tpl.php will effect only to field's formatter. not to widget

Comment: oh that looks good, but i don't know if that's necessary in my case. the above worked perfectly. but if i come to limitations (who knows), i will give your solution a try. thanks! :)